# System.Single accuracy with C#

Tags: c#, floating-point, rounding

In the example below the number 12345678.9 loses accuracy when it's converted to a string as it becomes 1.234568E+07. I just need a way to preserve the accuracy for large floating point numbers. Thanks.

```
Single sin1 = 12345678.9F;
String str1 = sin1.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(str1); // displays 1.234568E+07
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to preserve decimal numbers, you should use `System.Decimal`. It's as simple as that. [`System.Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.aspx) is worse than `System.Double` in that as per the documentation:

> By default, a Single value contains only 7 decimal digits of precision, although a maximum of 9 digits is maintained internally.

You haven't just lost information when you've converted it to a string - you've lost information in the very first line. That's not just because you're using `float` instead of `double` - it's because you're using a floating *binary* point number.

The decimal number 0.1 can't be represented accurately in a binary floating point system no matter how big you make the type...

See my articles on [floating binary point](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) and [floating decimal point](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx) for more information. Of course, it's possible that you *should* be using `double` or even `float` and just not caring about the loss of precision - it depends on what you're trying to represent. But if you really *do* care about preserving decimal digits, then use a decimal-based type.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Simple as that. In memory your number is 12345679. Try the code below.

```
Single sin1 = 12345678.9F;
String str1 = sin1.ToString("r"); // Shows "all" the number
Console.WriteLine(sin1 == 12345679); // true
Console.WriteLine(str1); // displays 12345679
```

Technically `r` means (quoting from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)) `round-trip: Result: A string that can round-trip to an identical number.` so in reality it isn't showing all the decimals. It's only showing all the decimals needed to distinguish it from other possible values of `Single`. If you want to show all the decimals use `F20`.

If you want more precision use `double` or better use `decimal`. `float` has the precision that it has. As we say in Italy "Non puoi spremere sangue da una rapa" (You can't squeeze blood from a turnip)

Answer (score 0):

You could also write an IFormatProvider for your purpose - but the precision doesn't get any better unless you use a different type.
this article may help - http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/